# Proper use of quotation marks

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should one stick to American style of placing punctation marks within quotes if one uses the american spelling of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48872/should-one-stick-to-american-style-of-placing-punctation-marks-within-quotes-if)

This may seem infantile, and it probably is a bit.

If your final line in a paragraph happens to be a quote, do you

"end it like this."

OR

"end it like this".

Comment: The sogenannte "American style" is stupid, and the only reason anybody should ever use it is because they're being paid to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is correct.

[Lots of good reading](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=period%20at%20end%20of%20quote) on this site about this.