# Exclamation mark at the end of a quote and end of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, quotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should end punctuation go inside quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/when-should-end-punctuation-go-inside-quotes)

Is the grammar at the end of the following sentence correct? If not, what should it be?

> I was told in no uncertain terms "this is our decision to make!".

Comment: That is not grammar. That is punctuation.

Comment: You don't really elaborate on why you're confused, which can make a question difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Exclamation points, quotation marks, and periods (end stops) are not grammar but punctuation marks, a subset of *writing mechanics*.

There's no need for the period at the end of the sentence.