# "Snapping out" vs "snapping out of it."

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

I wrote the following:

> Eri was still staring at the screen, but her eyes were expresionless,
>   as if in a trance.
>
> Her father laughed. "I admit it was a shocking footage. But Eri, you
>   look like you've just seen a ghost."
>
> "Oh," Eri said, **snapping out (of it)**. "It's nothing. I just had a long
>   day."

Should I just write, *snapping out*, or *snapping out of it*?

Comment: By the way, _footage_ is not countable, so it should be _it was shocking footage_, no _a_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean something like ‘desist from (an attitude, etc.), to change a mood, pattern of behaviour, etc., by sudden effort’, then you need to write ‘snapping out of it’.

Comment: But you want a comma - not a full stop - after "it".

Comment: @TrevorD Why? It's OK with the full stop.

Comment: @StoneyB It seems an unnecessary break. I would have said that "Eri said ... it" is parenthetical needing just commas at each end; and that, if not interrupted by that clause, the spoken first sentence would have been "Oh, it's nothing." and therefore should remain uninterrupted by a full stop.

Comment: @TrevorD But it might equally be, "Oh. It's nothing." Author's call, for whatever linereading she hears.

Comment: @StoneyB In which case, there shouldn't be a comma inside the initial quotation marks.

Comment: @TrevorD No, that's conventional before the 'she said' sort of thing. `"Oh." she said.` would be odd in US typography, as would be my own preference: `"Oh" she said.`

Comment: @StoneyB I said *inside* the quotation marks. If the first bit were a separate 'sentence', I would have expected *"Oh!", she said ...* or maybe *"Oh", she said ...* - but including the comma *as part of* the quotation suggests that it was *not* the end of a sentence.

Comment: @TrevorD Not in US typography, which has a different set of arbitrary rules than British typography.

Comment: @TrevorD Punctuation within quotation marks is a US thing. I'm sure I read a question about it here somewhere... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/when-should-end-punctuation-go-inside-quotes

Answer (score 3):

To say that someone is snapping out colloquially means that they are being [snippy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snippy). It carries the sense that the person is willfully or conscientiously acting out.

The phrase "snapping out of it" is more in line with your description.

> as if in a trance.

It denotes a more 'back to reality' experience, having Eri be engaged in thought and then snapping back to reality.

Comment: Reached this discussion exploring these very same two options. Most prolific dissection ever - thank you, Az Za!