# Why does the comma, period, and question mark always go inside the quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation, quotes

I see that this question has been asked before, but it was resolved as a duplicate. But the question that it supposedly duplicated was clearly not the same question because it didn't address the question "Why."  I would really like to know the reason for this convention, especially since it's not the same in England and our language is English. Did we change it as a way of revolting against England? I don't buy the answer that we did it just because it looked better.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you are referring to *[How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/)*, the accepted answer notes "They are called typesetter's quotes because when typesetters were laying out the typesetting blocks putting the small blocks for punctuation inside the quotes made the layout more stable and less prone to shift around." If you mean *[Why is the period placed inside the double quote, at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150703/)* see @Algernon_Asimov's entire answer.

Comment: Excuse me and I worked with properly qualified typesetters on a good dozen publications for 20-odd years, during which time obviously, questions about quotes often arose. No typesetter, nor writer nor editor nor producer nor publisher I ever discussed style with ever once said anything about *typesetters' quotes* nor would have dreamt of suggesting anything so obviously untrue as that *putting the small blocks for punctuation inside the quotes made the layout more stable and less prone to shift around*. Try it and see for yourself…

Comment: Why anything, including punctuation marks, goes inside quotation marks is because those marks distinguish between what the original speaker said at the time and what the commentator is saying now.

That there might be difficulties is a challenge to be overcome, not an argument for breaking the rules.

Comment: What did you mean by *it's not the same in England and our language is English*, please? What does *Did we change it as a way of revolting against England* mean?