# Quotation Marks

Tags: punctuation

I'm an American living in the USA. Is it permissible to punctuate thusly, i.e., insert the commas and periods outside the quote marks?

• When Joe called me a "schlep", I was offended.

• The terms "prevaricate", "tergiversate", and "masticate" rhyme.

• Make sure to enter the log-in password "geeksquad 4".

• Nancy said, "I heard Lou say, 'Be careful what you wish for'." (Is the '." ending correct here?)

• Joe said, "Respect your elders". (Thinking it should be: Joe said, "Respect your elders.")

Thanks.

Comment: The guidelines for punctuation will be set forth in whichever style guide you are following. See also *[When should end punctuation go inside quotes?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548)* among many others.

Comment: There are ten related questions in the sidebar.

Comment: Who's stopping you? Who do you need permission from? If you try to write a column for a newspaper or magazine doesn't use this style, they'll change them. But otherwise, you can use "logical" quote marks.

Comment: All correct, in my opinion, except number 4.

Answer (score -1):

According to all literary style guides, you always put punctuation marks within quotation marks. The prevalence of putting punctuation outside of quotation marks I think might be related to the rise in programming languages, which are very logic-oriented, and use *strings* or *values* inside of a pair of quotation marks (**" "**) to create an entry point for the programming language to use as a reference. So it makes logical sense to write your entry as:

```
"Sally".code{}
```

rather than

```
"Sally."code{}
```

This is conjecture, however; it could easily be coincidence.

Comment: -1. See my answer for reason.

Comment: @WS2 It seems they've been altered since I went to school.

Comment: I think it depends on which country you went to school in.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm sorry if I had not allowed for that fact. So are you saying that in the OP's final example you would have put the stop inside the close quote?

Comment: @PeterShor I draw my experiences as an American in the US, and shaped my response around that, too, since that's the context of the question.

Comment: @WS2 regarding PeterShor's insight, from primary through post-secondary school, if I wrote those five bullet points, only bullet #4 and probably #3 would be marked correct by my professors. But we also weren't taught to add quotation marks around terms in such examples as those; we'd just write the words plainly into the sentence. Generally, only quotes deserved double quotation marks; in severe cases, we'd use **' '**.

Comment: I'd say the first three are "logical" punctuation, which is gaining in acceptance in the U.S. these days, although they would have been deemed wrong by the teachers when I went to school. The last two are plain wrong in the U.S.—if you quote a complete sentence, there should only be one period, and it should go inside the quotation marks.

Comment: @PeterShor not sure what you mean by **there should only be one period** ...there is already only one period in the 4th and in the 5th bullet items.

Comment: @Tyler: This was a proactive comment. I've seen people try to put in two periods, one because  the quotation is a complete sentence, and one for the original sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor Ah, gotcha. At any rate, did you say #4 was wrong because the period should be inside the single quotation mark as well as the double quotation mark?

Comment: Yes, I think #4 is wrong because the period should be inside both quotation marks, because the interior quotation is a complete sentence.