# Integrating quotes from a short story into an essay for better flow

Tags: quotations

I am working on Freytag Pyramid and wish to integrate a direct quote from the text with my sentences.

Example

Original Text:

```
There was a white horse spreading its wings of fury over the horizon.
```

Integration (1):

```
One thing it liked to do was to "[spread] its wings of fury".
```

Are ellipses needed at the beginning and end of the quote?

Integration (2):

```
One thing it liked to do was to "[spread] its wings of fury over the horizon".
```

Can the period be omitted inside the quote?

As for providing a source of the quote in the text, I would do something like this

```
In second paragraph, the protagonist states that she "was unhappy with her social status".
```

Is there a much more elegant way to cite the source of the quote in the text, so I won't have to include `In the second paragraph, the protagonist states...`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include ellipses when the quoted portion is part of the complete sentence:

> One thing it liked to do was to "[spread] its wings of fury."

This usage is correct.

Appropriate punctuation in quotes is detailed in *[When should end punctuation go inside quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7548/6006)* The answers there also apply to this usage.

As for providing a source, you can include a detailed citation in a footnote or endnote:

> The protagonist states that she "was unhappy with her social status."[1]
>
> ...
>
> [1] Page 1234, line 4.

The actual citation should match the appropriate style guide requested by either your professor or your publication. It also wouldn't hurt to verify that footnotes/endnotes are appropriate.