# Position of punctuation in proper title with quotes

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Take the following sentence with punctuation purposefully omitted:

> Do we have an Italian restaurant right next to the Video Outpost "Too"

Video Outpost "Too" is a proper title, specifically the name of a store. In American English, we are taught that when ending a quote, if said quote is at the end of a sentence, the final punctuation goes inside of the ending quotation mark, such as in the example below.

> He said, "today is a nice day."

However, does this rule still apply when the quotation marks are not part of a quote but are a stylistic choice on the part of the name? More specifically, which of the two forms below is correct or most correct?

> Do we have an Italian restaurant right next to the Video Outpost "Too"?
>
> Do we have an Italian restaurant right next to the Video Outpost "Too?"

Forgive me if this is a duplicate. I've found questions regarding actual quotes, but nothing for this particular situation.

Edit: I would appreciate answers for both the American and British conventions, if possible. I believe this question will be of help to a wider audience if both conventions are provided, assuming there are multiple conventions.

Edit 2: As [TeacherKSHuang](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/211575/teacher-kshuang) noted, this is similar to the question of whether punctuation goes inside or outside of quotation marks, however the [linked question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/when-should-end-punctuation-go-inside-quotes) only covers cases when the quotation marks are used as markers of a quotation. This specific question refers to quote marks that are part of a proper name and are not used as quotation marks.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: since the question mark is not part of the name itself, you don't include any quotes around it, even though it's at the end of the sentence. Only include punctuation in quotation marks if it's part of the punctuation in the actual quote.

Comment: Hi, Foxtrek_64. I had marked this question as a duplicate, but reading it again, I can see where you might be confused because you think because it's a name, it will be different. Personally, as an American, I would put the question mark outside the quotes because the question mark is not part of the name (as you say).

Comment: AmE: Your rule about final punctuation does apply to the question mark. However, the period is an exception in going inside no matter what.

Comment: KSHuang, while this question may not be a duplicate, I believe the linked question may contain the correct answer, being what you said in your comment. I think the correct convention would be to preserve the wholeness of the title, therefore requiring you to place the punctuation outside of the quotes. If you could answer the question with that, perhaps citing the linked question, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: You ask for a British-English answer as well: in British English (BrE), we do **not** include punctuation within the quotation *unless the punctuation is actually part of the quotation*. This applies even if the quotation is at the end of a sentence.

Comment: AmE, and as far as I know, BritE also: "Did he say what I think he said?  Did he say, "today is a nice day"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it depends on whether what you're quoting is a sentence.  If you were to say: 'He said "it's a nice day."' then the punctuation would go inside the quotes as it is a full sentence that 'he' is saying.  However, if you were to say:  Do we have an Italian restaurant right next to the Video Outpost "Too"? Then you would put the punctuation mark outside of the quotes because the word "Too" is not a sentence and merely a title.