# Citations and Commas

Tags: grammar, commas, questions, citation

How do you write #1?
Does #2 need a comma before the word, while or no comma at all?

1. "How is it? Do you like it? she would ask.
2. And that is how we would carry on with our mother/daughter dinners each night of the week while my dad was at work.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct if you add a quotation mark after the second question (see [Handling quotes ending in exclamation or question marks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3917) and [this guidetogrammar page](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/marks/quotation.htm)):

> "How is it? Do you like it?" she would ask.

The second sentence is a case of joining an independent clause (everything before the "while") with a dependent one ("while my dad was at work"). Because the independent clause comes first here, you do not need a comma (see [butte.edu tip sheet](https://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/indep_clause.html)).

> And that is how we would carry on with our mother-daughter dinners
>   each night of the week while my dad was at work.